# If $a$, $b$, $c$ are sides of a triangle, prove $2(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq3(a^3+b^3+c^3+3abc)$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, triangles, substitution, geometric-inequalities

> $a$, $b$, $c$ are sides of a triangle, prove:
>   $$2(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq3(a^3+b^3+c^3+3abc)$$

What I have tried:
$$
⇔2\sum (a+b)ab\geq \sum a^3+9abc
$$
so I can't use 
$$\sum a^3+3abc\geq \sum ab(a+b)$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3):

WLOG $$c=\max\{a,b,c\}\implies a=x+u,b=x+v\text{  and  }c=x+u+v (x>0, u,v\ge 0)$$

Then your inequality is equivalent to

$$x(u^2-uv+v^2)+2(u+v)(u-v)^2\ge 0*\text{true}*$$

Comment: Of course, BW forever! :)

Answer (score 3):

Let $a=y+z$, $b=x+z$ and $c=x+y$.

Thus, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positives and we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^3-x^2y-x^2z+xyz)\geq0,$$ which is Schur.

Answer (score 1):

Also, we can use SOS here.

Indeed, by your work we need to prove that 
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^2b+2a^2c-a^3-3abc)\geq0.$$

Now, let $a\geq b\geq c$.

Thus, since $$3b-a-c=b+c-a+2b-2c>0,$$ we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^2b+2a^2c-a^3-3abc)=\sum_{cyc}(2a^2b+2a^2c-4abc-a^3+abc)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\left(2c(a-b)^2-\frac{1}{2}(a+b+c)(a-b)^2\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(3c-a-b)\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{2}((a-b)^2(3c-a-b)+(a-c)^2(3b-a-c))\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{2}((a-b)^2(3c-a-b)+(a-b)^2(3b-a-c))=(a-b)^2(b+c-a)\geq0.$$

Comment: Can down-voter explain us, why did you do it?

Comment: (+1) Nice idea but i think you have a typo. I dont know why since $3b-a-c>0$ you have the this line $\geq\frac{1}{2}((a-b)^2(3c-a-b)+(a-c)^2(3b-a-c))$. My english is very bad, sorry.

Comment: I think it's should that  $3b-a-c>0\rightarrow (a-c)^2(3b-a-c)\ge 0$. Then you need prove $\geq\frac{1}{2}((a-b)^2(3c-a-b)+(b-c)^2(3a-b-c))\geq \geq\frac{1}{2}((c-b)^2(3c-a-b+3a-b-c))=\frac{1}{2}((c-b)^2(2a-2b+2c))\ge 0$

Comment: @Word Shallow I proved that $3b-a-c>0$. See please better my proof.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg, Sorry, I didn't get either for instance if we have $b=c=1$ and $a=5$, then $3b-a-c=-3<0$.

Comment: @MathArt $a$, $b$ and $c$ are sides-lengths of a triangle. See please a given.

Comment: Yes, it is rigorous and right $3b-a-c=b+c-a+2b-2c>0$ for $a\geq b\geq c$ triangle sides.